# Add 'name' attribute to 'select' tag depending on selected 'li' class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-select, jquery-chosen

My 'select' list transformed by 'chosen.js' to 'ul' list, but searching function depends on the 'name' attribute' of 'select' listing.

```
<select name="test">
    <option  value="1">Пункт 1</option>
    <option  value="2">Пункт 2</option>
    <option  value="3">Пункт 3</option>
    <option  value="4">Пункт 4</option>
</select>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="parent result-selected">one</li> (selected option)
        <li class="active-result">two</li>
        <li class="active-result">three</li>
        <li class="active-result">four</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to change the 'select' name from 'test' to 'parent' when 'li' with 'result-selected' class also contains 'parent' class.

```
var select = document.querySelector('select');
select.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var name = this.querySelector('option:checked').id;
     select.name = name;
});
```

this code based on option 'id' and it works until that is 'select' listing, but don't work with 'chosen.js' transformation to 'ul' listing

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on the `ul` tag. Check for changes in class attribute. If the class attribute is changed, get the `li` with class `result-selected` and see if it has class `parent`.

```js
const selectEle = document.querySelector('select');

const targetNode = document.querySelector('ul');

const config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

const callback = function(mutationList) {
  for (let mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
      if (mutation.attributeName == "class") {
        const selectLi = document.querySelector('.result-selected');
        console.log('Before-', selectEle.name);
        selectEle.name = (selectLi.classList.contains('parent')) ? "parent" : "test";
        console.log('After-', selectEle.name);
      }
    }
  }
}
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

observer.observe(targetNode, config);

const li = document.querySelector('li');
li.classList.add('parent');
// li.classList.remove('parent');
```

```html
<select name="test">
  <option value="1">Пункт 1</option>
  <option value="2">Пункт 2</option>
  <option value="3">Пункт 3</option>
  <option value="4">Пункт 4</option>
</select>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="result-selected">one</li> (selected option)
    <li class="active-result">two</li>
    <li class="active-result">three</li>
    <li class="active-result">four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much, it should works, but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

It states in the [documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) that it has its own event handler; the syntax is `$("#form_field").chosen().change(…);`.

So in your case, try;

```
$("select").chosen().change(function(){
    ... code here
});
```

Comment: But I don't know how it works if the 'id' is in the 'option' tag and doesn't include to the 'li' tag.